# Derby.js (Racer) access control

Tags: node.js, derbyjs, racerjs

I'm new in Derby.js environment, and as far as I see Racer is exposing all the data on client side.

So, basically anybody could manipulate any data stored on server?
Am I correct? Is there any way to manage access control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is plugin for Racer - [racer-access](https://github.com/codeparty/racer-access)

Use it like this:

```
var racerAccess = require('racer-access');
derby.use(racerAccess);
store.allow('change', 'users', function (some usefull arguments) {
    return true || false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

At now [racer-access](https://github.com/codeparty/racer-access) is deprecated. You can use [share-access](https://www.npmjs.com/package/share-access).

Answer (score 0):

It seems share-access is now deprecated in favor of [sharedb-access](https://github.com/dmapper/sharedb-access).

Here's a [related discussion on the Derby mailing list "racer-access deprecated".](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/derbyjs/LaiCtRrsB8k)